# Increase size of legend box and adjust space between legend entries

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am trying to make a custom legend that should contain circles of different sizes. I have two problems:

1. The first problem is that the space between the circles seems to be fixed according to the center of each circle. However, the visual effect is not great, and I would like to adjust such space in order to have an equal space according to the border of the circle. Any suggestion?
2. The second problem is related to the size of the grey legend box. Is there any way to customize the size so the circles are within the borders?

Here the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

line1 = Line2D([0],[0], color="white", marker='o', markeredgecolor='k', markersize=40)
line2 = Line2D([0],[0], color="white", marker='o', markeredgecolor='k', markersize=32)
line3 = Line2D([0],[0], color="white", marker='o', markeredgecolor='k', markersize=24)

plt.legend((line1, line2,line3),('Thing 1','Thing 2', 'Thing 3'), numpoints=1, 
labelspacing = 3, handletextpad=1.5)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: #2 is easy: just add `borderpad=1.8` to `plt.legend`

Comment: #1 is hard inside the confines of matplotlib but easy to correct in inkscape.

Comment: I actually just noticed that matplotlib basically keeps the labels equidistant (even though the symbols are not). So perhaps, it is graphically better in this way...